# How to move a pin on the MKMap?

Tags: ios, dictionary

I can remove the pin and then add it to new place, but I need to move it from one place to other with animation. That is the simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
   [UIView animateWithDuration:duration 
                       delay:delay
                     options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn 
                  animations:^{
                       [someAnnotation setCoordinate:someAnnotation.coordinate];  
                 } 
             completion:nil
     ];
```